# what's the purpose for the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()

Tags: log4net

I saw someone put log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator() inside the AssemblyInfo.cs. What exactly does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

```
// Configure log4net using the .config file
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
// This will cause log4net to look for a configuration file
// called TestApp.exe.config in the application base
// directory (i.e. the directory containing TestApp.exe)
// The config file will be watched for changes.
```